# Ubuntu 13.10 Installation Issues on a Lenovo W510

Tags: 13.10, hardware, lenovo

I installed Ubuntu 13.10 x64 on my Lenovo ThinkPad W510 laptop via a Live USB key.  During installation, my hardware works.  After installing and rebooting, various hardware no longer works (ie. touchpad, network card, wireless card, USB ports, etc.).  Graphics work, but they are in low resolution, as if video drivers are not installed.

Comment: @Mr. Lee  Thank you for your response.  I have tried installing with 3rd party software both checked and unchecked.  I have also tried installing with and without downloading updates during the installation process.

Answer (score 0):

Install 3rd party software during installation.